# Is -std=c++2a necessary at link stage as well?

Tags: g++

If I compile in two stages, using a particular language standard:

```
g++ -std=c++2a -c file1.cpp                   #compile source files 
g++ -std=c++2a -c file2.cpp
g++ -std=c++2a file1.o file2.o -o program     #link 'em
```

...can I leave the `-std=c++2a` out of the link command, or is it sometimes needed?

Version is gcc 10.

Comment: I am not aware of anything it does enable, but unless it is problematic, I would keep it on the command line. You never know if at some point it might trigger linking with the filesystem or parallel part of the standard library...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are compiling on Linux with a *recent* [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/). Be sure to read more [about C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) and about your particular compiler (i.e. [GCC 9](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-9/) is not the same as [GCC 10](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/)). Check with `g++ --version` what it is.

In *practice* you want to compile [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) warnings and debug information (in [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) for [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) inside your [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) object files and executables), so use

```
g++ -std=c++2a -Wall -Wextra -g -c file1.cpp
```

and likewise for `file2.cpp`

Later (once your program is correct enough, e.g. has few bugs) you could want to ask the compiler to [optimize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) it. So you could use

```
 g++ -std=c++2a -Wall -Wextra -O3 -g -c file1.cpp
```

Practically speaking, you'll configure your [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool (e.g. [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/)) to run your compilation commands.

In *rare* cases, you could want to use [link time optimizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interprocedural_optimization). Then you need to both *compile* and *link* with `g++ -std=c++2a -Wall -Wextra -O3 -g -flto` and perhaps other options.

Be aware that link time optimization could almost double your build time.

You could also be interested by [static analysis](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2020/03/26/static-analysis-in-gcc-10/) options [of](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Static-Analyzer-Options.html) GCC 10 (or even by writing your own static analysis using [GCC plugins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html)).

Comment: So can I leave the -std=c++2a out of the link command, or is it sometimes needed?

Comment: It is needed with `-flto` as my answer explains